# Make TortoiseHg use a separate Mercurial package

Tags: python, windows, mercurial, tortoisehg

I have installed Mercurial as a Python package. Now I want TortoiseHg to work with them. However, all versions of TortoiseHg are bundled with its own version of hg and Python libraries. How do I make sure that TortoiseHg is using Mercurial which I have installed?

Comment: why do you want this? I'm curious

Comment: @Eli, I'm extending Mercurial and want to test if it works with TortoiseHg correctly.

Comment: Isn't TortoiseHg an open-source project? Then you can install it and build it from sources, where you surely can modify every aspect of its runtime

Comment: What do you mean by *I'm extending Mercurial*. Have you created [normal](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/UsingExtensions) Mercurial extension or have you modified Mercurial modules directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm extending Mercurial and want to test if it works with TortoiseHg correctly

It is good to test compatibility with both official Mercurial binaries and TortoiseHg.

They are organized the same way. Namely, all Python binaries are stored in `library.zip`

So to make your extension working with either of these bundles, you need to include your extensions (either in `.py` or `.pyc` form) into `library.zip` and configure the extensions in `Mercurial.ini`.

While it may be possible to force TortoiseHg to use another Mercurial installation, it is better to offer users of your extension a way to use it without adding extra Mercurial installations to their systems. So you can just provide an instruction on how to integrate your extension into `library.zip`.

Comment: It's not necessary to add Mercurial extension to `library.zip` file. It's enough to specify full path to the extension in Mercurial's configuration file.